# "Even if + present tense" vs. "Even if + past tense"

Tags: tense

In the post ["alternate" vs. "substitute"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/251422/116345), I wrote

> Even if I **misunderstand** the rule quoted, which means, using "alternate" does not have to have multiple choices are presented, I guess "substitute" still work.

I am trying to suggest a hypothesis because I don't know whether my understanding there is correct.

However, no matter my understanding there is correct or not, another question doesn't have to be modified.

In this particular context, should I use the present tense version shown as the quotation or the past tense version shown below?

> Even if I misunderstood the rule quoted ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Even if I misunderstand` is good here because you're not sure whether your understanding is correct or not.

`Even if I misunderstood` would imply that you know for sure your understanding is correct. The past tense (technically past subjunctive) refers to something that is not true, at least in the speaker's belief.

Likewise `If I misunderstand, please correct me` makes sense, while `If I misunderstood, please correct me` does not.